# MYSQL/PHP find the most common item associate with a given item

Tags: php, mysql

I have thousands of user generated wish lists of items

the table is something like

```
collectionId |  itemdId  | user_id
-----------------------------------

    123      |    2345  |    1
    123      |    3465  |    1
    123      |    876   |    1  // <---
    123      |    567   |    1           
    123      |    980   |    1  // <---

    777      |    980   |    2  // <---
    777      |    332   |    2
    777      |    3465  |    2
    777      |    876   |    2  // <---
    777      |    678   |    2
    777      |    567   |    2
    ...           ...       ...
etc..
```

you see item 876 and 980, are included in both collections (777 and 123) so they are a popular couple/pair

So say I visit the page of item 876
I'd like to display to my users that a very common item associated/wished together with it, it's the item 980 (of course this is based on users'taste)

> Think for a moment what Amazon does, if you see a white iphone i want
>   to suggest you a pink iphone cover because many other users have
>   suggested/favorited that together with the white iphone

in PHP I would probably do something loopy like in pseudo code

```
for total number of collection:

select all item from collection 1

  select all item from collection 2
  do array_interesct (c1,c2)
  store the matching items
  repeat...

  select all item from collection 2
  do array_interesct (c1,c3)
  store the matching items
  repeat...

...then elect all item from collection 2 and repeat all the iterations..
```

but i'm wondering if this can be accomplished with MYSQL only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a query that gets all the collections that contain the item you selected:

```
SELECT collectionId
FROM wishLists
WHERE itemId = 876
```

From this, you want to get all the other itemIds in those collections.

```
SELECT itemId
FROM wishLists
WHERE collectionId IN (above query)
AND itemId != 876
```

This can be rewritten as a join:

```
SELECT a.itemId
FROM wishLists AS a
JOIN wishLists AS b ON a.collectionId = b.collectionId
WHERE a.itemId != 876 AND b.itemId = 876
```

Now you can count the repetitions of this to find the most common ones:

```
SELECT a.itemId
FROM wishLists AS a
JOIN wishLists AS b ON a.collectionId = b.collectionId
WHERE a.itemId != 876 AND b.itemId = 876
GROUP BY a.itemId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Add a `LIMIT n` clause at the end to show the top n items.

Comment: my bad...actually the results where sorted differently and i thought it was falsed...it actually works like magic! thanks again